# Forward traffic on port to another host with transparent proxy

Tags: iptables, forwarding, transparent-proxy

I have a host with ip `$HOST_IP` which runs an HTTP server on port 8080. There is a transparent proxy server running on port 9000 on host with IP `$PROXY_SERVICE_IP`.

I'm trying to forward traffic from the original host to the proxy server. I have these two `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination $PROXY_SERVICE_IP:9000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $PROXY_SERVICE_IP --dport 9000 -j SNAT --to-source $HOST_IP
```

They work great, I get the packet to the proxy server.

The problem:
The proxy server tries to resolve the original request, by make the request to the host, but that traffic is redirected to the proxy, so it ends up in a loop.

What `iptables` rule could I use to prevent this? When the proxy server makes a request to the host disable the forwarding? I tried to add `! -s $PROXY_SERVICE_IP` to the rules above, but it didn't work.

Comment: why not use nginx or apache as proxy? you don't need a second program to do the same, that's called reverseproxy

Comment: My use case is different, the transparent proxy is custom, provides e.g. mocking based on rules.

Comment: sorry but this site is not for fun, what is the business related question and use case? if, and it looks nearly 100%for this, your question fits to superuser.com

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by business related question. I'm not doing this for "fun", but in a business if that's what you mean.

Comment: It turns out `! -s $PROXY_SERVICE_IP` works perfectly well - the only problem in my case was, that the IP address actually was incorrect.